# Avoiding auto expansion of columns in RawSQL

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

Apologize for the multiple questions on this topic. I am trying to update a column based on other columns in a table and so far nothing seems to be working. I tried updateWhere and then rawSQL with update ([Ambiguous Type Error When Using RawSql Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007484/ambiguous-type-error-when-using-rawsql-update)) but both have issues.

updateWhere does not allow other columns names (only values) so that's ruled out.

I tried rawSQL with an Update but it is automatically expanding all the entity names which breaks the update. If there is a way to stop it from expanding column names (not putting ?? does not solve that problem), that will work perfectly. For example if I do:  `Update table SET X = Y - ? [input values]` , it creates `UPDATE table.f1, table.f2, etc. SET X = Y - ? [input values]`

This is one of those queries that I want to run in the background as an admin so I don't care for type safety. If there is a way to blindly execute a SQL string, that will work as well.

All I want to do is : SET X = (Y - Constant).  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried myself, but from reading the module documentation, I think [`rawExecute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/persistent/latest/doc/html/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v%3arawExecute) is what you are looking for.

You might also what to file a bug report for `persistent`. I don't think `rawSql` is supposed to do column name expansion for anything but `??`. At the least, it's an omission in the documentation even if it's the desired behavior.

Comment: thank you! It works fine with rawExecute and I removed the type signature at the end of my call. I was able to reproduce this issue with a brand new Yesod project so I will report it.